# PHP image upload and crop with url

Tags: php, image-processing, image-uploading

I am using the below upload class for image upload and manipulating.
[class.upload.php samples, a files uploading and images manipulation PHP class](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_samples.htm)

Now I want to change form input type="file" to a text field where I will give a Image URL.
How can I make this uploading class to work.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

this class seems to accept url's as arguments as well so just change the input type to `text`, name to for example `image_url` and use this line to manipulate the image as you wish after submitting the form:

```
$handle = new upload($_POST['image_url']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the file name through text box and in background use php curl function to upload the file in the server and your uploading class will work fine
[PHP Curl to upload file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php)